# How to write the following query?

Tags: sql

The query for the output below:

```
SELECT ce.date, p.courseExecution_date
FROM courseExecution AS ce
LEFT JOIN participant AS p
ON ce.courseID = p.courseExecution_courseID
WHERE ce.courseID = 2 and p.personID = 4;
```

Output:

```
    |     date     | courseExecution_date |
     --------------------------------------
    |  2017-12-05  |      2017-12-05      |
    |  2017-12-08  |      2017-12-05      |
    |  2017-12-09  |      2017-12-05      |
    |  2017-12-12  |      2017-12-05      |
```

I only want to show the dates to the user that he did not sign up for, like this:

Expected result:

```
|     date     | 
 ---------------
|  2017-12-08  |
|  2017-12-09  | 
|  2017-12-12  |
```

How should the query look like? Many thanks.

Comment: Why not give us sample table data and the expected result instead?

Comment: Side note: your `LEFT JOIN` is a regular `(INNER) JOIN` because of the condition referencing the table in the `WHERE` clause.  (Personally, databases should probably at least return a warning, because that's almost certainly not what's intended)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not very clear but I guess you need query like this

```
SELECT ce.date
FROM courseExecution AS ce
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
   SELECT 1
   FROM participant p
   WHERE ce.courseID = p.courseExecution_courseID and
         p.personID = 4 and
         p.courseExecution_date = ce.date
) and ce.courseID = 2
```

`NOT EXISTS` works as a difference between sets (which is probably what you want)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming **courseExecution_date** is the date user signed up for.
You need an additional condition in your where statement:

```
SELECT ce.date, p.courseExecution_date
FROM courseExecution AS ce
LEFT JOIN participant AS p
ON ce.courseID = p.courseExecution_courseID
WHERE ce.courseID = 2 and p.personID = 4
and ce.date <> p.courseExecution_date
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple conditions with left join:

```
SELECT 
  ce.date, 
  p.courseExecution_date
FROM 
  courseExecution AS ce
  LEFT JOIN participant AS p
  ON ce.courseID = p.courseExecution_courseID
     and ce.courseExecution_date!=p.date
WHERE  
  ce.courseID = 2 
  and p.personID = 4;
```